# How to create distorted gradient banding?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photoshop-effects

The top image briefly was translated into the bottom one for a split second as it was loading in an app.

**Question**

How can I intentionally make an image distort like this:

Original image

[image: original image]

What I want to re-create

[image: what I want]

**I've tried**

Low compression in Photoshop but I'd also like the horizontal bands at the top and bottom that accidentally occurred.

What sort of program would allow me to change the axis/oscillation of images and pixels in such a way, I guess like controlling it like analog video. Any help or points in the right direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I totally understand what you want to achieve here. The best practice for this would be to get the Glitch app on your mobile phone and import your pictures to photoshop for further segmental edits.

For Windows or Android  you can get it here [Glitch App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lucagrillo.ImageGlitcher&hl=en)

or for ios [Glitch app for IOS](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/glitche/id634467171?mt=8)

You can play around and experiment with many styles.

However if you don't have a smartphone to get the apps than here are few tutorials you can imitate and experiment with.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRlqgzq8mxw

Hope my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like pixelization and then color reduction (to like 8 colors) with dithering

[image: pixelization]

[image: reduction]

possibly with some palette editing

Another possible option is to convert the first gradient to a super low quality jpeg (programs like GIMP let you control quality)

I imagine the original (glitched) was created by storing a super low-res and low-color version of the image and then just scaling it up without any smoothing.